# How to get records of last working day using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query an `SQL` database to get all purchased products on last working date. For example, on `Monday` I need to get the records of `Saturday`. Also suppose due to some reason `Tuesday` is my leave I need to get the records of `Monday`.
I tried my query like:

```
select ProductName , count(ProductName) as [No Of Products],SUM(Total) as [TotalCost] 
from dbo.TransactionDetails 
where CurrentTime >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
    AND CurrentTime <dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) 
    and  Transaction='BUY' 
group by ProductName
```

But here I am only getting the details of last date.

Also I tried by checking on my last closed shifts:

```
select ProductName , count(ProductName) as [No Of Products],SUM(Total) as [TotalCost] 
from dbo.TransactionDetails 
where CurrentTime = (select MAX(CurrentDateTime) from CloseShifts) and  Transaction='BUY' 
group by ProductName
```

But the problem is here I am not getting any result as the below query returns `DateTime` and on that particular time I don't have any transactions.

```
select MAX(CurrentDateTime) 
from CloseShifts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 select ProductName , count(ProductName) as [No Of Products],SUM(Total) as [TotalCost] 
    from dbo.TransactionDetails 
    where CurrentTime >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,(select MAX(CurrentDateTime) 
    from CloseShifts)),0) 
    AND CurrentTime <dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,(select MAX(CurrentDateTime) 
    from CloseShifts)),0) 
    and  Transaction='BUY' 
    group by ProductName
```

Comment: I am not getting any rows.

Comment: TransactionDetails table contains columns like ID,TransactionMode(Buy and SELL),Total and CurrentTime 
CloseShifts contains columns like Id,TotalSales,TotalPurchase,CurrentDateTime

In CloseShift  I insert one record per day at closing time

Answer (score 3):

`select ProductName , count(ProductName), SUM(Total), MAX(CurrentDateTime) from "dbo.TransactionDetails"`
 `inner join` with CloseShifts on your condition between two table (because you diid not provides the table)"

Comment: I am only retrieving Last working date from the CloseShifts.Its returns only last closed datetime of last transactions

Comment: can you give your table structure and is it that you only want to know about your last working days transaction

Comment: TransactionDetails table contains columns like ID,TransactionMode(Buy and SELL),Total and CurrentTime CloseShifts contains columns like Id,TotalSales,TotalPurchase,CurrentDateTime In CloseShift I insert one record per day at closing time

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you need to drop the "Time" part of your DateTime columns, so how about casting both DateTimes as Dates, e.g.:

```
... where Cast(CurrentTime as DATE) = (select MAX(Cast(CurrentDateTime as DATE)) ...
```